Decoding Aztec Barcode information from Ticket
I have an Aztec barcode that I am trying to decode. When I try to do so, I get the same exact string every time and it is encoded. There is no information about what encoding is used, so I am reaching out for some insight .I tried reading it online and expected to find the data in plaintext. Instead I got encoded data which i have no idea how to parse and display. I used https://www.onlinebarcodereader.com/.
The encoded string is the following:
x^[XÉXÕá°$9%3%Ë/+¹Ò·ÊÑÈÏ19ÈõÉ(Êwwò¬4MNÌIÏô625Ó54²H,)02021014105´0°dTnZRê Rdh�1';#À©(4-('97³,Ñ$9µ¢�b©yeTrJqHCJq&;"º¦$Çå%¨\U¦rS&d¦¤»ø;YøE9ÉK+óKKÁêJ+ ¬À¶m560ÒxÃØ�è WAMAC¹891/3Q¡FA¹,5O(¤\XYáÕ÷ëÃþ«ª_-»/×4gü¹râ_wCé]¿ò×úì©:-~éÏ]e¥t¢óÞû¬eGUíîÇÇ6vZ¬×z mêvÿÙwÐcùûÀÕ- eN�9Mñ 
The hex values for the string follows:
78 5e 5b c2 94 58 10 c3 89 58 c3 95 1c c3 a1 c2 b0 24 39 25 33 25 c3 8b 2f 2b c2 b9 c3 92 c2 b7 c3 8a c3 91 c3 88 c3 8f 31 39 1b c3 88 c3 b5 c3 89 c2 8a 28 c3 8a 77 77 c3 b2 c2 ac 34 4d 4e c3 8c 49 c3 8f c3 b4 08 36 32 35 c3 93 35 34 c2 b2 48 2c 29 30 32 30 32 31 30 31 34 0c 31 30 35 c2 b4 30 c2 b0 c2 8c c2 8a 64 54 6e c2 8e 08 5a 0e 52 c2 97 c3 aa 0a 52 c2 97 c2 9c c2 99 c2 99 c2 92 64 68 00 31 27 3b 23 c3 80 c2 a9 28 34 2d 28 27 39 37 c2 b3 2c c3 91 24 39 c2 b5 c2 a2 00 62 c2 82 c2 a9 c2 81 79 c2 88 c2 91 c2 91 c2 91 c2 85 c2 89 65 54 72 4a 71 01 48 43 4a 71 26 c2 92 3b 22 c2 ba 16 02 05 1b c2 97 c2 a6 24 c3 87 c2 97 c3 a5 25 1a c2 82 c2 a8 5c 08 55 02 c2 a6 72 53 c2 9a 16 26 c2 97 64 c2 a6 c2 a4 c2 bb c3 b8 1a 3b 59 c3 b8 45 01 39 05 c3 89 c2 8d c2 8b c2 92 c2 93 13 4b c2 92 2b c3 b3 4b c2 93 4b c2 8a 12 c3 81 c3 aa 4a c2 92 2b 1c 0c 0d c2 ac 1c c3 80 c2 b6 1a 1b 01 6d 35 36 30 c2 88 c3 92 c2 87 78 c3 83 c3 98 00 c3 a8 08 20 57 41 4d 41 43 c2 b9 38 39 31 2f 33 51 c2 a1 46 41 c2 b9 2c 35 4f 13 28 c2 a4 5c c2 9e c2 9a c2 9a c2 9d c2 92 58 59 1c c3 a1 c2 90 c3 95 c3 b7 c3 ab c3 83 c3 be c2 ab c2 aa 5f 2d c2 bb 2f c3 97 34 0b c2 98 67 c3 bc c2 99 c2 b9 72 c3 a2 c2 8e 5f 77 43 c2 8f c3 a9 5d c2 bf c3 b2 c3 97 c3 ba c3 ac c2 a9 17 3a 2d 7e c3 a9 1c c3 8f 5d 65 c2 a5 74 0b c2 a2 c2 96 c2 9f c3 b3 c3 9e c3 bb c2 ac 65 47 55 c3 ad c3 ae 0e c3 87 c3 87 36 76 5a c2 ac c3 97 7a 02 0a c2 98 6d c3 aa 76 c3 bf c3 99 77 c3 90 63 c3 b9 c3 bb c3 80 13 c3 95 2d 0a c2 89 65 4e c2 89 c2 86 00 39 4d c2 90 c3 b1 0a 
The image of the aztec barcode is submitted with this post.
Anything helps, thank's in advance!
Image of Aztec barcode
